# How to find if entire week(s) past from creation on mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a solution to find with mySQL every result that was created since a(or many) entire week(s) (7 days).

I tried this but it seems sometimes the result is false because is there more than one result per week.

```
SELECT *
FROM `datatable`
WHERE MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created),NOW()),7)=0;
```

- created is a timestamp.

Thanks for any response!

Comment: Try this

    `WHERE date_add(created, interval 7 DAY) = NOW()`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have all the same work with a search constraint, I can not limit myself to one week, X weeks goal. I change my where with `MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DATE(created), CURRENT_DATE()), 7 )=0`. It seems working better.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. "More than one result per week" what's wrong with that? And why would that make "the result" "false"?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit +1, I don't understand the question either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)
```

If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since
'1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as
seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC, date may be a DATE string, a
DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the format YYMMDD or
YYYYMMDD. The server interprets date as a value in the current time
zone and converts it to an internal value in UTC. Clients can set their
time zone as described in
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html.

So, do not use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function, but simple `DATE()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `datatable`
WHERE 1 
    AND `created` >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
    AND `created` <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand the question, you want the records that are are newer than a ***certainDate***, **AND** not older than 7 days, or 14 days,..., 140 days (whichever of them is closest to the ***certainDate***) from current date.

**IF** I understand you correctly, following might work for you with `certainDate = '2013-04-01 00:00:00'`

```
SELECT *
FROM `datatable`
WHERE `created` >= ADDDATE(
                    '2013-04-01 00:00:00', 
                    INTERVAL MOD(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), '2013-04-01 00:00:00')),7) DAY
                  )
```

This query will fetch all results having `created` in last 14 days.